# Batch If file with filename exist

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

The Situation is that i convert m4a to mp3 files with ffmpeg.

now i need a function that checks if file test.mp3 is also in the folder as test.m4a and deletes the test.m4a.

Thank you for your help.

```
:start


for %%a in ("path\*.m4a") do ffmpeg -y -i "%%a" path\converted\%%~na.mp3"


timeout /T 10  > nul

goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohk, this should work:

```
:start


for %%a in ("path\*.m4a") do (
ffmpeg -y -i "%%a" path\converted\%%~na.mp3"
if exist %%a if exist %%~na.mp3 del %%a
)
timeout /T 10  > nul

goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete the m4a file if the same MP3 file exists in path\converted, otherwise it will process the m4a file.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("path\*.m4a") do (
    if exist "path\converted\%%~na.mp3" (
        del "%%~a"
       ) else (
        ffmpeg -y -i "%%~a" "path\converted\%%~na.mp3"
    )
)
```

Comment: it would be awesome if it could check if it already exists in path\converted

Comment: Do you want to check if the file already exists?  And do what with it?

Comment: it should check if the file mp3 was created in path\converted and delete the m4a version in path\

Comment: Check the changed answer above.